# Is an $L^p$-sphere in Sobolev space $H_2^{s}(\Omega)$ a Hilbert manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, morse-theory

For a bounded smooth  domain $\Omega$, let  $H_2^{s}(\Omega)$ be the usual Sobolev space on $\Omega$.

Define $A:=\{f\in H_2^{s}(\Omega)| \lVert f\rVert_{L^p(\Omega)}=1\}$ where $2<p<2_{s}^*$.

Can we show  $A$ is a $C^2$-Hilbert manifold since I need to use the Morse lemma?

Comment: When you say "since I need to use the Morse lemma", do you perhaps mean something more like "possibly using the Morse lemma"?

Comment: @LSpice, no, my purpose is using morse lemma on A, but generally, morse lemma holds only on a $C^2$-Hilbert manifold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The norm map
$$
f\mapsto \int_{\Omega} f^p dvol
$$
is a $C^k$-map for $k<p$ and in fact smooth if $p$ is an even integer as is shown in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/24901438.) of Bonic and Frampton. The implicit function theorem for maps of Banach spaces then applies to give your desired result.